# Export Data from Azure SQL Server SP or table to Excel using Azure Resources

Tags: sql, azure, export

I am having few data which gets returned from my Store procedure or table from Azure SQL Server,
Client is having some formatted excel and I need to export data from SP to that formatted excel.
The excel has pre defined columns with different name than DB Column names .
Is it possible by using any Azure resources like Azure data factory or logic Apps to export data from sql server and append in the excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Azure Data Factory -Data Flow Activity we can achieve this.

Source here is SQL Database where column names are coming from Table:

[image]

Connect Sink(Target) and in the Mapping Tab uncheck Auto Mapping and Add Output column names as required at the target :

[image]